# what let us to add same vector to both side of equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading 'linear algebra done right'

it gives the definition of vector space

> cummutativity.
> $u+v = v+u$ for all $u,v \in V$
>
> associativity
> $(u+v) +w = u + (v + w),  (ab)v = a(bv)$ for $u,v,w \in V$ and $a, b \in F$
>
> additive identity
> there exists an element $0 \in V$ such that $v+0 = v$ for all $v \in V$
>
> additive inverse.
> for every $v \in V$, there exists $w \in V$ such
> that $ v+w=0$
>
> multiplicative identity.
> $1v =v$ for all $v \in V$
>
> distributive properties.
> $a(u+v)=au + av$ and $(a+b)v = av + bv$ for all $a, b \in F$ and all $u,v \in V$

That's it. It does not give me what $u+v$ means or how I can compute it.

How do I know then, I can add same vector to both sides of equation?

given $v = w$, what allows me to do $v + z = w + z$?
(Suppose you wanna prove the following. There exists a unique $x \in V$ such that $ v+3x = w $)

Only thing I see has the power to let me do that is the commutativity
$u+v = v+u$ for all $u, v \in V$

given $v = w$,
I can pick any vector $z \in V$ and claim $v + z = z + w$
and $v+z = z+w = w+z$ as desired.

But then I feel like I'm exploiting 'commutativity'?

Comment: Addition is a function $f:V\times V\to V$, and we denote $f(u,v)$ by $u+v$. You are allowed to add between any two vectors in $V$. If $v=w$ then $(v,z)=(w,z)$ as ordered pairs, and so clearly $f(v,z)=f(w,z)$.

Comment: yes the book says that. by definition of function, you are allowed to do that.. I see . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't need to be one of the axioms. It's more fundamental than that. It's a property of equality. If $v$ and $w$ are the same thing, then after adding $z$ to both of them they will still be the same thing.